# Fullscreen plugin in redactor

Tags: redactor

I click on fullscreen button in redactor, However, an error in the console enter code here `this.fullscreen.enable is not a function`. And on enter click or paste text in new paragraph is added `<span></span>` ???
In general, there are not the best impressions of working with the editor.

Comment: Not getting any errors on my end (using Craft 2.3.2620 on Safari). Perhaps a missing component?

Comment: no, fullscreen.js present

Answer (score 1):

Like Douglas suggested, you may not have the JS file you need so make sure you download the latest build and upload the files.